# Link to Rails root URL when root is on a subdomain

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, subdomain

So I have a Rails app with a static controller and two routes:

1. `match '/', :to => "static#dashboard", :constraints => { :subdomain => "dashboard.alpha" }`
2. `root :to => "static#home"`

The root is on `alpha.mydomain.com` and the second page is on `dashboard.alpha.mydomain.com`.

How can I link back to the root dynamically with Rails? The root_url variable is just `/` and using `root_url(:subdomain => false)` sends me to mydomain.com.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you just want to get to alpha.mydomain.com and never to mydomain.com, you could make root_url always point to the alpha subdomain by doing this:

```
root :to => 'static#home', :subdomain => 'alpha'
```

And in the view you can just use:

```
<%= link_to 'home', root_url %>
```

Was that something like what you had in mind?

Comment: After testing it again i found out that it did not work the way I hoped, it adds the subdomain before the subdomain you're at e.g. if you're at alpha.domain.com the links generated with root_url will point to alpha.alpha.domain.com.
I'll look into it a bit more..

Comment: Seems to not do that for me. Even if I'm already on alpha. and I go to the root URL, your answer takes me to the same page, it works perfectly.

Comment: Awesome, might have something todo with my /etc/hosts configuration then maybe.
I'm glad it worked out!

Comment: Tried it with a lvh.me (an url that links to 127.0.0.1) and then rails understood that blog.lvh.me was a subdomain and skipped to prepend another subdomain when using root_url. So it must have been something with my local dns setup, I'll have to read up on that...